# Hibernate não salva oneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu tenho uma relação 1 -> n entre Conexao e Relatorio.
As classes são as seguintes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conexao")
public class Conexao {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "CONEXAO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="conexao")
private Set<Relatorio> relatorios;

  //getters and setters
}
```

A classe Relatorio:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relatorio")

public class Relatorio {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "RELATORIO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONEXAO_ID")    
private Conexao conexao;

public Relatorio(Conexao conexao){
       this.coxexao = conexao;
}
   //getters and setters
}
```

Estou executando assim:

```
   public Teste(){
   ConexaoDao  conDao = new ConexaoDao();
   Conexao con = conDao.buscar(new Long(6)); // aqui, tudo certo, ele tras a 
   conexao corretamente

  Relatorio relatorio = new Relatorio(con, "teste777", "teste555", "teste333");
  con.getRelatorios().add(relatorio);

  RelatorioDAO relDao = new RelatorioDAO();
  relDao.salvar(relatorio); // ele salva o relatorio, com a conexao preenchida corretamente

  }
}
```

Os Daos:

```
public class ConexaoDAO {


public void salvar(Conexao conexao){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    sessao.save(conexao);
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}

public void editar(List<Conexao> lista){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    lista.forEach(conexao -> sessao.update(conexao));
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}

public void excluir(List<Conexao> lista){
    excluirRelatorio(lista);

    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    Query query;
    for(Conexao conexao: lista){
        query = sessao.createQuery("delete Conexao where id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", conexao.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();

}

private void excluirRelatorio(List<Conexao> lista){
    List<Relatorio> listaRelatorioExclusaoDummy = new ArrayList<Relatorio>();
    Set<Relatorio> setDummy;

    for(Conexao conexao: lista){
        setDummy = conexao.getRelatorios();
        listaRelatorioExclusaoDummy.addAll(setDummy);
    }
    RelatorioDAO relatorioDao = new RelatorioDAO();
    relatorioDao.excluir(listaRelatorioExclusaoDummy);
}



public List<Conexao> listar(){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = sessao.createQuery("from Conexao"); 
    List<Conexao> conexoes = query.list();
    sessao.close();
    return conexoes;
}


public Conexao buscar(Long id){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Conexao conexao = (Conexao) sessao.get(Conexao.class, id);
    sessao.close();
    return conexao;
}

public void excluir(Conexao conexao){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    sessao.delete(conexao);
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}

public void editar(Conexao conexao){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    sessao.update(conexao);
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}


}
```

E RelatorioDao:

```
public class RelatorioDAO{

public void excluir(List<Relatorio> lista) {
    excluirColuna(lista);

    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
    Query query;
    for(Relatorio relatorio: lista){
        query = sessao.createQuery("delete Relatorio where id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", relatorio.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}

private void excluirColuna(List<Relatorio> lista){
    List<Coluna> listaColunaExclusaoDummy = new ArrayList<Coluna>();
    Set<Coluna> setDummy;

    for(Relatorio relatorio: lista){
        setDummy = relatorio.getColunas();
        listaColunaExclusaoDummy.addAll(setDummy);
    }
    ColunaDAO colunaDao = new ColunaDAO();
    colunaDao.excluir(listaColunaExclusaoDummy);
}

public void editar(List<Relatorio> listaRelatorioDummy) {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();

    listaRelatorioDummy.forEach(relatorio -> sessao.update(relatorio));

    transacao.commit();
    sessao.close();
}

public void salvar(Relatorio relatorio) {
    Session sessao= null;
    try{
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.save(relatorio);
        transacao.commit();
    }finally{
        sessao.close();
    }
}

public List<Relatorio> listar() {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = sessao.createQuery("from Relatorio"); 
    List<Relatorio> relatorios = query.list();
    sessao.close();
    return relatorios;
}


}
```

e a minha classe HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
}
```

Porém, quando vou carregar o relatorio, ele tras a conexão com os campos nulos. Sendo que quando eu debuguei o codigo, verifiquei que a conexao passada como parametro para o construtor de Relatorio, está com todos os campos preenchidos.

O mais estranho ainda é que quando eu olho no Postgres, a tabela relatorio, tem a coluna CONEXAO_ID preenchida corretamente.
Não entendi pq o Java não está trazendo a conexão com todos os nulos. A conexão trazida não é nula, mas seus campos sim. Alguém poderia me ajudar???

Vou colocar as imagens pra ser mais explícita:

Essa imagem mostra a conexao setada em relatorio. Como vcs podem ver, os campos de conexão estão todos preenchidos.
[image: Campos da conexão preenchidos]

[image: Quando listo todos os relatórios e verifico o qual acabei de salvar, a conexão que na linha acima estava preenchida, agora vem com todos os campos nulos]

Comment: Olá, obrigada pela resposta.. mas acredito que não seja isso, já que faço um consulta em seguida e os campos retornados são nulos. Coloquei uma imagem pra ilustrar o que acontece

Comment: Coloca o código do seu DAO. Os valores devem estar nulos porque alguém deve estar fechando a conexão.

Comment: Oi Giuliana, obrigada pela ajuda.. Coloquei lá as classes